# SQL query "sum up two column -1 from current row and column-2 from the previous row and store in column 3"

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to write a sql query. where I enter values of cllection, bidding and loan.
Rest everything should be calculated automatically and store in the database.
I am not able to sum the current row and the previus row. Could someone help me please?

```
SQL Tables:- id is AI, NOT NULL and rest all INT and NULL
    id collection bidding tender  balance loan interest cf
```

SQL query :-

```
START TRANSACTION;
Insert INTO chit(id, collection, bidding) VALUES (0, 500000, 225000);
UPDATE chit SET tender = collection - bidding;
UPDATE chit SET balance = bidding + cf;
UPDATE chit SET loan = 225000 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
UPDATE chit SET interest = loan * 0.02;
UPDATE chit SET cf = interest + loan; 
COMMIT;
```

Calculations:-

```
balance = collection - bidding + cf (cf values should be from the previus row) 
cf = balance + interest 
interest = loan * 0.02 
tender = collection - bidding 
collection : Input 
bidding : Input 
loan : Input
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSKxT.png)
[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   and Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Iterations (calculate first row, from that calculate second row, from that calculate third row, etc.) are done with recursive queries in SQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). Running totals etc. can also be achieved with window functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html). For both of these approaches you need MySQL 8. If you run an old MySQL version, you may get this to work with variables somehow, which is usually tedious and prone to errors.